# jQuery Yii Update Data Table, Only if Tab is Shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, yii, tabs

I have written a JavaScript code to update yii GridView table after every 10 seconds displayed to users which is working fine.

```
timedRefresh($page_refresh_time);
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
     setTimeout(function(){refreshGrid()}, timeoutPeriod);
}

function refreshGrid() {
   $.fn.yiiGridView.update(\"group-grid\");
   timedRefresh($page_refresh_time);

}
```

But now I want to change my code so that table is refreshed only when tab is shown and rest of the time table is not refreshed. So I changed my code to:

```
timedRefresh($page_refresh_time);
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
     setTimeout(function(){refreshGrid()}, timeoutPeriod);
}

function refreshGrid() {
   $('a[href=\"#dash2\"]').on('shown', function(e) {
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update(\"group-grid\");
        timedRefresh($page_refresh_time);
   });
}
```

where `dash2` is the id of the tab. Now the problem is that that after updating my code the refreshing of table after every 10 seconds has topped working. Can anyone please guide me where I am making a mistake in the above JavaScript code?

Also I want the table to stop refreshing once tab is closed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'shown'` is not a valid jQuery event. Anyway, your use of `on()` for this scenario is wrong.

Change your above code to:

```
function refreshGrid() {
   if($("a[href='#dash2']").is(':visible')) {
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update(\"group-grid\");
   }
}
var interval = setInterval(refreshGrid, $page_refresh_time);
```

If you need to cancel the refresh, use

```
if(interval) clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel for the solution and for updating my knowledge regarding 'shown' since I am new to jquery, javascript stuff.